# cocos2d-x project gives error while building in android studio

Tags: android, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am new in cocos2d x and i have a build error when importing my project in android studio. I don't know if it already have been asked but I didn't find an answer suitable to my problem.

When I build my project in terminal it works fine but in android studio it gives error:

> Error:(147, 86) java:  is not abstract and does not override abstract method isHideLoadingScreen() in com.alipay.android.app.IRemoteServiceCallback

Comment: i think i should @override  method isHideLoadingScreen() but i don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide some code but anyways something like this should work -

```
@Override
public boolean isHideLoadingScreen() throws RemoteException {
        return false;
}
```

Put this code inside your `IRemoteServiceCallback` class.

Comment: thanx @omerjerk actually i have imported my cocos2d x project and did not do anything in android studio. And i am unable to modify    IRemoteServiceCallback      class because it does not allow it